# Best practice to modify NPM package in Angular 2

Tags: angular, npm

I installed a 3rd party NPM package in my Angular 2 application. For the requirement in my application, I had to modify the NPM package within node_modules. I know once this is deployed in another environment, the changes I have made within node_modules is going to vanish. What is the way forward in this kind of scenario where I have made changes to the NPM package.

Thanks.

Comment: if you make changes, they will only disappear if you redownload that module from npm. why do you think they disappear when they are deployed?

Comment: I am making  the changes in development. As a standard practice, we dont push the node_modules folder to the Git. Eventually when you build the app in the server, it will download the package.

Comment: so you mean they will change once in git and someone tries to clone the project, thats not the same as deploying

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to **fork this NPM package into your private repository**, then make changes, then load your forked package in `package.json` of your project.

I had the similar problem and this scenario worked perfectly. The only problem is to keep your forked version up with changes from original library. From time to time you should merge changes from original repository into your repo.

Comment: Best approach if you are sure that your pull request to that package will be rejected :)